# How docker container in one machine communicate with another container in another machine

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

I am running cassandra as docker image in one machine (ubuntu 14.04) and I replicate my node application in 4 docker containers in another machine that is also ubuntu. From these 4 nodes i want to listen the cassandra

Comment: You will have to be more precise. But your Cassandra server has an IP and a port which is listening. Use them from your 4 containers.

Comment: Expose the port number.

Comment: All communication between containers happen as network connections only to exposed ports.  You need to tell your four nodes the name and port of your cassandra service as Docker knows it.

Comment: Already I exposed the port no and also i am able to listen Cassandra in devcenter through host machine IP address. But still I don't know how to listen from node application. I tried with the same host Ip but "All host tried query exception came

Comment: You should use the name of the docker instance to refer to it from other docker instances.

Comment: If it is running in a same machine then we can listen through names. How another machine get to know about the docker container name